# What is the use of Horner's Method?

Tags: polynomials

Here is Wikipedia's explanation of Horner's Method:

> Given the polynomial
>
> $$
> p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \cdots + a_n x^n,
> $$
>
> where $a_0, \ldots, a_n$ are real numbers, we wish to evaluate the polynomial at a specific value of $x$, say $x_0$.
>
> To accomplish this, we define a new sequence of constants as follows:
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> b_n & := a_n \\
> b_{n-1} & := a_{n-1} + b_n x_0 \\
> & {}\  \  \vdots \\
> b_0 & := a_0 + b_1 x_0.
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Then $b_0$ is the value of $p(x_0)$.
>
> To see why this works, note that the polynomial can be written in the form
>
> $$
> p(x) = a_0 + x(a_1 + x(a_2 + \cdots + x(a_{n-1} + a_n x)\cdots)).
> $$
>
> Thus, by iteratively substituting the b_i into the expression,
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> p(x_0) & = a_0 + x_0(a_1 + x_0(a_2 + \cdots + x_0(a_{n-1} + b_n x_0)\cdots)) \\
> & = a_0 + x_0(a_1 + x_0(a_2 + \cdots + x_0(b_{n-1})\cdots)) \\
> & {} \ \  \vdots \\
> & = a_0 + x_0(b_1) \\
> & = b_0.
> \end{align}
> $$

**Question:**

Is the point of this algorithm that we can now evaluate $p(x_0)$ without having to ever evaluate any of the values $x_0^2, \ldots, x_0^n$, and instead, we are able to just just iteratively compute $b_n$ through $b_0$, where by the time we eventually get to $b_0$ we are finally able to evaluate $p(x_0)$?

If this is the case, why is this useful? Why not just compute $p(x_0)$ the normal way?

---

**EDIT:** Is it true that using Horner's rule to compute a polynomial of degree $n$ takes running time from $\Theta(n^2)$ down to $\Theta(n)$?

Comment: You said it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, exactly as you said. This is used to decrease the number of multiplications, so it is more efficient than computing it the normal way.

Example:

> You have the polynomial $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$.
>   Computing directly you have six multiplications: (a * x * x * x, b * x * x, c * x). With Horner $((ax + b)x + c)x + d$ you have three multiplications: (a * x, first parenthesis * x, second parenthesis * x)

It is important to remember that in floating point calculations results from these two methods (direct and Horner) will differ.

Comment: I would suggest something for future use:  if you are happy with answer accept it, if not share your doubts in comment.